# Hide select block while "selecting" and option

Tags: php, html, html-select

I've tried to hide the  section unsuccessfully. I need to hide it while at the same time making on option valid. Here is what I have:

```
    <select id="country_code" name="country_code" style="width:160px;">
    <?php
    if(count($GLOBALS['countries_codes_allowed'])>0) {
        foreach($GLOBALS['countries_codes_allowed'] as $ind=>$value) {
            echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$ind.'</option>';
        }           
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

I tried using the hidden tag, and it hid the section, however the option was not selected and the form did't work.
I'm new at this. Any help will be appreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please clearly explain *what you're trying to do* and *what is not working*.

Comment: Do you want to hide it when the list of options is opened or after an option is selected?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being very clear. I was able to hide it and still make it work while placing the hidden tag in <select>. Thanks anyways guys!